# What kind of "actions" does the Pull request Webhook of the Github pull request builder support?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pull-request, github-webhook, ghprb

I applied Job triggering using the "Github pull request builder" plugin in "jenkins".

So, I checked that the job is triggered when a **new PR is created** in the Github Repository, a **new commit is pushed** to the PR, and the **PR is re-opened**.

However, there are many actions that I haven't checked, but I couldn't find the part that specifies what kind of Pull request webbook "actions" ghprb supports.

Does anyone know the answer?

Thank you.

**pull request actions**

```
Pull request opened, closed, reopened, edited, assigned, unassigned, review requested, review request removed, labeled, unlabeled, synchronized, ready for review, converted to draft, locked, unlocked, auto merge enabled, auto merge disabled, milestoned, or demilestoned.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/blob/ebd6df7b593865c65ae87ef78a0d8255cc90fada/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/ghprb/GhprbRepository.java#L396

I found it's answer

```
edited, opened, reopened, synchronize
```